# 2022: Get LinkedIn Posts via Access Token

Tags: api, linkedin-api

I have been looking for an updated version of how to retrieve my own posts from LinkedIn via an access token which I have received from completing a three-legged OAuth process.

I have reviewed: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/community-management/shares/share-api?view=li-lms-unversioned&tabs=http#permissions- but its now showing as legacy.

Comment: As it seems, LinkedIn unfortunately no longer wants us to retrieve this kind of content:
"Find Posts by authors is only supported for organization authors. Finding by member authors is not supported."

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/community-management/contentapi-migration-guide?view=li-lms-2022-09

Comment: @KarlHofmann you might as well write this as an answer for the bounty.

Answer (score 0):

As it seems, LinkedIn unfortunately no longer wants us to retrieve this kind of content:

> "Find Posts by authors is only supported for organization authors.
> Finding by member authors is not supported."
> [Source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/community-management/contentapi-migration-guide?view=li-lms-2022-09)

Neither a good, nor a solution within the LinkedIn-TOS (I assume) would be to use a webscraper. I have seen some solutions online but they are all very pricey in my opinion (and you never know if they get shut down by LinkedIn)

Answer (score -3):

{
"activity": "urn:li:activity:12345657",
"content": {
"contentEntities": [
{
"entity": "urn:li:article:0",
"entityLocation": "https://www.example.com/content.html",
"thumbnails": [
{
"imageSpecificContent": {},
"resolvedUrl": "https://www.example.com/image.jpg"
}
]
}
],
"description": "content description",
"title": "Test Share with Content"
},
"created": {
"actor": "urn:li:person:A8xe03Qt10",
"time": 1471967236000
},
"distribution": {
"linkedInDistributionTarget": {}
},
"id": "6173878065928642560",
"lastModified": {
"actor": "urn:li:person:A8xe03Qt10",
"time": 1471967237000
},
"owner": "urn:li:organization:123456789",
"text": {
"text": "Test Share!"
}
}

Comment: I need more information.